# Would mechanical engineering work robotics and if not what field does?

Tags: robotics

I ask this because I want to get into robotics(mainly the building of it), so I wanted to go to college to learn mechanical engineering but now that I have found out so many different types of engineering(other than just mechanical and electrical, which are what I thought where the only engineering degrees) I don't know for sure which one would be best for me.

Comment: Do robots use levers? That is classic mechanical engineering...

Comment: This seems to be a question about your future studies choice which is likely to get closed.

Comment: What I'll use it for is, but I don't think the question itself is. Also is future studies a Stack exchange because then I could just be switched over there.

Comment: So you should check the list of stacks...

Comment: Electrical and Mechanical would both be strong suitors for this.  Quite often a mechanical engineer (depending on field) will require some electrical knowledge for dealing with power for motor and actuators.  Computer Science at my university was part of the Electrical department.  That degree will play a strong part in programming controllers, and how the robot will behave.

Comment: So based off of what you said about the different types of engineering, Mechanical(and electrical) engineering would mainly deal with the building of robots?

Comment: There are many flavors of robotics and it is more applied engineering rather than one specific field.  Although mechanical engineering may seem more appropriate for the design, the challenges are more software / embedded controllers.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like an [academic guidance question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/261/1832). Such questions often involve personal choice and can probably be better answered by an adviser or counselor. We do not believe this site's format is well-suited to such questions, which are therefore considered off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mechanical engineering is an excellent choice for a person interested in robotics. In the mechanical engineering field, you will learn about:

-modeling the dynamics of mechanical systems and control systems theory

-strength of materials and materials engineering, including materials selection

-kinematics of mechanisms

-machine design, including bearings, cams, levers, gearboxes, limit switches, screw drives, belt drives and the motors that power them

-manufacturing methods, including machining, welding, casting, and bolted assemblies.

Comment: mechanical engineering spends a lot of time on thermo issues that likely are throwaway for a machines and electronics focus.

Comment: no, it depends on your area of specialization.

Comment: I've never seen a straight ME curriculum that didn't include heat transfer and thermodynamics 1 & 2.

Comment: still a good idea to have exposure to those things...

Comment: sure, but not if you want to specialize.  Engineering is too broad to know everything.  EE had to decide this in thee 80s

Answer (score 0):

Mechatronics is the relatively new engineering discipline that combines mechanical and electrical engineering, with robotics right at the forefront.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechatronics

Comment: Mechatronics is usually included in either or both the mechanical engineering or electrical engineering program. But yeah I am a mechatronics engineer.